# How to use netstandard 2.1 with xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, net-standard-2.1

I am running Visual Studio 2019 preview and I have the Android preview sdk installed (9.0.99)
But when I try to build a xamarin forms project with a library set to netstandard 2.1. I still het a compatibiliteit error with monodroid.
What am I missing? Been searching quite a bit and found something about a mono 2019-06 I believe, but no info on how to get it.

Comment: have you tried latest Xamarin.Android 10 versions with 16.3 preview?

Comment: Did a small test and the latest visual studio preview works using net standard 2.1. 
Didn’t find time in the past to try nightly so can’t confirm but I believe it would have worked to.

Comment: This situation also makes it impossible to use EFCore 3 with Xamarin Forms since EFCore 3 targets .NET Standard 2.1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#netstandard21

Comment: @SeanAnderson [EF Core 3.1 uses NS2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18141) and NS2.1 support is available since 16.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [github document shows that Xamarin Android](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) support NS2.1 since [version 10](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/commit/97ebed68ee2f2a737884e1e3b09093f060816760#diff-a0efca2faa45606b03f5b824d6213122):

[image]

So if you use at least Visual Studio 16.3 you can use .Net Standard 2.1 in Xamarin Android apps.

Comment: What is Xamarin.Android 10? Android Q?

Comment: @LucaZiegler [Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android) provides open-source bindings of the Android SDK for use with .NET managed languages such as C#" And this also needs a version number and in version 10 of xamarin.android provides .net standard 2.1 support. The 10 indeed  indicates first Android 10 support.