# xamarin forms prism white screen

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, xamarin-forms-4

On Xamarin Forms I am using Prism MVVM.
After doing some update these two package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client  1.1.0->3.0.0  and Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.2.0->3.0.0** my application showing only white screen.

Can not see login page.

I only update these two package. Deleted bin and obj folder and it did not help

Other packages version:

**Prism.Forms-> 7.2.0.1367**

**Xamarin.Forms ->4.2.0.815419**

Any idea ?

**EDIT:**
All package I am using :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory">
      <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NdefLibrary">
      <Version>4.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Core">
      <Version>7.2.0.1367</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Forms">
      <Version>7.2.0.1367</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Plugin.Popups">
      <Version>7.2.0.573</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity.Forms">
      <Version>7.2.0.1367</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup">
      <Version>1.1.5.188</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory">
      <Version>4.5.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Notifier">
      <Version>3.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
      <Version>1.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.2.0.815419" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material">
      <Version>4.2.0.815419</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.HotReload">
      <Version>1.4.19</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**EDIT : Found new error**

Now I am getting these error. I got this error first removed signalR and readded it and checked the all "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type of field 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature:<Handler>k__BackingField' (1) 
due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000080 from typeref (
expected class 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler' in assembly 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60') 
assembly:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 type:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler 
member:(null)'
```

in debug windows

```
**System.TypeLoadException:** 'Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature:<Handler>k__BackingField' (1) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000080 from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler' in assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60') assembly:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 type:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler member:(null)'

**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

**Unity.ResolutionFailedException:** 'For more information add Diagnostic extension: Container.AddExtension(new Diagnostic())'

**Prism.Navigation.NavigationException:** 'An error occurred while resolving the page. This is most likely the result of invalid XAML or other type initialization exception'

**Prism.Navigation.NavigationException:** 'An error occurred while resolving the page. This is most likely the result of invalid XAML or other type initialization exception'
```

Comment: Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.815419 only works in VS2019. Do you use 2017?

Comment: No I am using VS 2019

Comment: I think problem is related to **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.1.0** package which installed on Xamarin Android. Because only this package left I did not update

Comment: always update all packages to same version for shared project and all apps

Comment: they all same but Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client. If I do it getting white screen :)

Comment: 1.1.0 is .net core 2.2 version. this client package also needs to be updated

Comment: That's the problem I can not update SignalR client If I do xamarin forms application showing only white screen

Comment: you need [Xamarin.Android 10](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-10-0-general-availability/) to have [.net standard 2.1 support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712521/1466046) so make sure you updated VS2019 to 16.3

Comment: I did all of you said but no change. Only package left to update is **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.1.0** If I update it to **3.0.0** my application is not working. I added all package I am using at xamarin android to my post

Comment: you need to [implement some changes from .net core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#signalr-1)

Comment: made all change and switch to JSON protocol to NewtonJson and still same.

Comment: Check Output logs to see some error / warning has been written or not... If you didnt find anything try setting... Exception Settings so that it throws exception when unhandled exception. In VS MAC > RUN > New Exception Catch Point > Create

Comment: got new error and added it the post @magicandre1981

Comment: again, this is caused by mixing versions. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.1.0 is .net core 2.2 and you can't really mix it with the 3.0 files.

Comment: well it's seems like but but can not find anything related to net core 2.2 in entire solutions

Comment: how often should I tell you that Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.1.0 is .net core 2.2

Comment: there is a misunderstanding here. I installed version 3 and got that error. I am not trying to install 1.1.0 to net core 3 ? ok?

Comment: You could use msbuild foo to capture a binlog and use the viewer to figure out who is pulling it in http://msbuildlog.com/

Comment: in the pages code behind wrap the initialiseComponent() in a try catch and see what the error is with a breakpoint. White screen usually means Xaml issue @S.AzizKazdal

Comment: The last comment from @Janwilx72 really helped. Please add your comment as answer so one can set it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad to hear @ChristophMett. I've added the comment as an answer as you have suggested

Answer (score 2):

In the pages code behind wrap the initialiseComponent() in a try catch and see what the error is with a breakpoint. White screen usually means Xaml issue

Comment: Absolute genius. This just saved my afternoon! Prism ioc also likes to fail silently with a white screen, and the inner exception caught this.